why are so many borders appearing when i hover my mouse instead of just a single one in nav-address
i am trying to clone an amazon website with just html and css for just now but i having problems
with border when hovering it to the nav-address
the html code
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Amazon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-logo border">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-address border">
            <p class="add-first">delivery to</p>
            <div class="add-icon">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
                <p class="add-second">India</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>

the css part
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: border-box;
}
.navbar{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #0f1111;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-logo{
    height: 50px;
    width: 113px;
}
.logo{
    background-image: url("amazon_logo.png");
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.border{
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.border :hover{
    border: 2px solid white;
}
/*box 2*/
.add-first{
    color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.add-second{
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.add-icon{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

i want to have only a single border instead of so many borders in nav address,there is a separate border for each div and paragraph in the div nav address,i dont want tht instead i just want a single border on juts nav address

maybe you meant to have a selector like .navbar:hover for that css rule? instead of using .border :hover. By the way your css is invalid because missing the selector on the first rule .. being possibly * or maybe body
